# How to navigate to next div in specific page on button click in Php?

Tags: php

I want navigate to other div on button click in specific page . How can i do it by header() function or any other function in Php?

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="" />

      <input type="submit" name="submit_request" class="submit_button" value="Sign up" />
</form>

<iframe name="my-iframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>
    <div id="text_submit" class="text-success">
        <p class="text-center">
            THANK YOU FOR SIGNUP WITH US.
        YOUR FORM SUBMITTED SUCCESSFULLY!
        </p>
    </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_request']))
    {
        $name= $_POST["fn"];
        $email= $_POST["ln"];

       header("location:my-iframe") // this is a div

    }
```

Comment: It's 2017 now. Avoid using `<iframe>`. Navigating to other DIV is client-side scripting, not server-side (i.e. not related to PHP).

Comment: i want to show a msg in a spcific page so how should i show that msg ?

Comment: can you use `action="my-iframe.php"` ?

Comment: my-iframe is not a page its a name of the iframe

Comment: then @Raptor said well.

Comment: Ok  thanks for helping :)

Comment: What is ur goal of doing this ? maybe there will be a better solution !

Answer (score 0):

to redirect to other page you must use `header()`
here is the syntax:

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
```

Comment: No sir i don't want to move/redirect to the other page i want redirect to the div in existing page

Comment: Is this possible?

Comment: redirect to the div means?? you want to show div after button clicked??